# Why is my HTML email coming out completely mangled in Gmail?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I've been banging my head against this problem for the last 6 hours. All the googling I've done so far is telling me that divs should work in emails after 2017. Every online html email tester I'm using shows my email as producing a perfectly well laid out email.

Then I send it in Gmail and it comes out a complete mess.

Here is the HTML rendered in browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOmP7.jpg

Here is the HTML when sent through Gmail:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y490j.jpg

Here is the HTML code itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Type"
      content="text/html charset=UTF-8 width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
      name="viewport"
    />
    <style>
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .email-container {
          width: 390px !important;
        }
        .big-divider {
          width: 324px !important;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 23px !important;
        }
        .h1-2 {
          margin-bottom: 23px !important;
        }
        .wine-pic {
          width: 324px !important;
          height: 262px !important;
        }
        h2 {
          font-size: 18px !important;
          width: 330px !important;
        }
        .test-promo-box {
          width: 226px !important;
          height: 42px !important;
          margin-bottom: 30px !important;
        }
        .desktop-icons {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .mobile-icons {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .female-founded {
          font-size: 12px !important;
        }
        .last-paragraph {
          width: 324px !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body
    style="
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: wheat;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    "
  >
    <div
      class="email-container"
      style="background-color: rgb(255, 252, 247); width: 600px"
    >
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center">
        <img
          style="
            margin-top: 28px;
            margin-bottom: 21px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
          "
          src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/BOXT_Final_Logo_Black_RGB.png"
        />
        <hr class="big-divider" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 0" />
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 28px; margin-bottom: 2px">
          YOU'VE EARNED
        </h1>
        <h1
          class="h1-2"
          style="
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            font-size: 28px;
          "
        >
          BOXT BUCKS!
        </h1>
        <img
          class="wine-pic"
          src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/wine_box.jpg"
          style="width: 503px; height: 406px"
        />
        <h2
          style="
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 500px;
          "
        >
          Thanks for referring your friend to BOXT! As a start-up, every single
          person who helps us spread the word about what we're up to makes a
          huge impact.
        </h2>
        <h2
          style="
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 500px;
          "
        >
          As a thank you, we're sending you $64 in BOXT Bucks! That'll get you
          your next BOXT on us — aka four bottles of fine wine delivered
          directly to your door from our Napa winery.
        </h2>
        <h2
          style="
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 21px;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 500px;
          "
        >
          Enter the code below at checkout when purchasing your next BOXT.
        </h2>
        <div
          class="test-promo-box"
          style="
            height: 42px;
            width: 226px;
            background-color: rgb(146, 191, 197);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 37px;
          "
        >
          <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px">TEST PROMO CODE</h3>
        </div>
        <hr class="big-divider" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 0" />
        <h2 style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 11px; text-align: center">
          WHY BOXT?
        </h2>
        <hr style="width: 18px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 25px" />
        <div
          class="desktop-icons"
          style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center"
        >
          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
              grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
              justify-items: center;
              align-items: center;
              width: 500px;
              margin-bottom: 29px;
            "
          >
            <img
              style="width: 102px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_1.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 46px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_2.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 51px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_3.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 80px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_4.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 64px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_5.png"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            style="
              margin-top: 10px;
              margin-bottom: 35px;
              display: grid;
              grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
              grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
              justify-items: center;
              width: 380px;
            "
          >
            <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 57px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_6.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 74px; height: 58px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_7.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 57px; height: 64px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_8.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 63px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_9.png"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-icons" style="display: none">
          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
              grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
              gap: 8px;
              justify-items: center;
              align-items: center;
            "
          >
            <img
              style="width: 102px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_1.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 46px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_2.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 51px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_3.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 80px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_4.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 64px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_5.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 57px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_6.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 74px; height: 58px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_7.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 57px; height: 64px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_8.png"
            />
            <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 63px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_9.png"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr style="width: 63px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 30px" />
        <p
          style="
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 0;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align: center;
          "
        >
          Questions? Contact hello@drinkboxt.com
        </p>
        <p
          style="
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align: center;
          "
        >
          @drinkboxt | drinkboxt.com
        </p>
        <hr style="width: 63px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 37px" />
        <h3
          class="female-founded"
          style="
            font-size: 13.5px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            text-align: center;
          "
        >
          FEMALE FOUNDED. BORN IN AUSTIN. MADE IN NAPA.
        </h3>
        <hr
          class="big-divider"
          style="width: 500px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 15px"
        />
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px; margin-top: 0">
          *Excludes profiles Three and Six
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 11px">
          DRINK BOXT LLC, 7601 S Congress Ave #150, Austin, TX 78745
        </p>
        <p
          class="last-paragraph"
          style="
            width: 500px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 11px;
            margin-bottom: 97px;
          "
        >
          *Offer valid in the form of BOXT gift cards. Redeem up to 12 months of
          BOXT on us. Offer cannot be combined with any other promotion or new
          member offers and discounts, subject to DRINK BOXT, LLC Terms &
          Conditions. Void where prohibited. Subject to DRINK BOXT, LLC Terms &
          Conditions. Members never pay shipping and can pause, change profile
          or cancel at any time. Subscription is ongoing until canceled. Email
          communication is intended for those 21+. Must be 21+ to order and
          receive wine shipment. Void where prohibited. DRINK BOXT, LLC cannot
          ship to AK, AR, DE, HI, IN, MS, RI, UT, WV.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried deleting various parts of the code, including the entire  block, the media queries, nothing seems to change the outcome.

If anyone could please help me figure this out, I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've coded an html email, but `table` is your friend. I don't think flexbox is supported.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Thank you, it looks like redoing everything in tables was the cleanest way to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I mean `<div>`s may work in emails but media queries don't, at least not in all email cients, and `display: flex` and `display: grid` DEFINITELY won't work -- emails are like using **HTML 4** so a lot of the modern conveniences don't exist. Take a look at the templates on [Cerberus](https://www.cerberusemail.com). These are the most solid email design patterns I know of. I have been using them myself for 5+ years now, in my eyes *[opinion]* -- this is the email standard. I mean Litmus even use it for their paid [email builder](https://www.litmus.com/email-builder)

Comment: Thank you for the link to Cerberus, that really helped point me in the right direction.

It looks like media queries do work, at least on gmail, but you're correct that flex and grid do not work.

I ended up having to just redo everything in tables. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helped! The main culprits when creating emails are gmail, all versions of Outlook and android -- these all have their own quirks. Just keep in mind that getting 100% uniformity across all email clients is impossible, especially as layouts get more complicated, gotta just try make the best of a bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like a lot of CSS is not supported in email still, for example flex and grid. Luckily, media queries are supported on gmail at least.

The solution in the end for me was to rewrite everything using tables. It now functions flawlessly.

Here is my functioning tables code for reference:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Type"
      content="text/html charset=UTF-8 width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
      name="viewport"
    />
    <style>
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .desktop-icons {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .mobile-icons {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .female-founded {
            font-size: 12px !important;
        }
        .unique-code {
          font-size: 16px !important;
        }
        .last-paragraph {
          font-size: 9.5px !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="email" style="width:600px;margin: auto;background:#FFFCF7; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;">
        <table role="presentation" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img style="
                  margin-top: 28px;
                  margin-bottom: 21px;
                  width: 20px;
                  height: 20px;
                " src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/BOXT_Final_Logo_Black_RGB.png">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      
        <hr class="big-divider" style="width: 85%; margin-top: 0" />
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 28px; margin-bottom: 2px">
          HERE'S $10 OFF
        </h1>
        <h1 class="h1-2" style="
                  text-align: center;
                  margin-top: 0;
                  margin-bottom: 16px;
                  font-size: 28px;
                ">
          YOUR FIRST BOXT!
        </h1>
      
        <!-- Header -->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <img class="wine-pic" src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/wine_box.jpg" style="width: 503px; height: 406px" />
          </tr>
          </td>
        </table>
      
        <!-- Body 1 -->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 30px 10px 15px;">
              <h2 class="unique-code" style="
                  text-align: center;
                  margin-top: 0;
                  margin-bottom: 5px;
                  font-size: 20px;
                  font-weight: 500;
                ">
                Enter the unique code below at
                </h2>
                <h2 class="unique-code" style="
                  text-align: center;
                  margin-top: 0;
                  margin-bottom: 0;
                  font-size: 20px;
                  font-weight: 500;
                ">
                checkout for $10 off your first BOXT.
              </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <div
                class="test-promo-box"
                style="
                  height: 42px;
                  width: 226px;
                  background-color: rgb(146, 191, 197);
                  margin-bottom: 37px;
                "
              >
              <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding-top: 11px;">TEST PROMO CODE</h3>
              </div>
          </tr>
          </td>
        </table>
      
      <hr class="big-divider" style="width: 85%; margin-top: 0" />
      
        <!-- Body 2-->
      <div class="desktop-icons">
        <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 102px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_1.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 46px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_2.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 51px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_3.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 80px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_4.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 64px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_5.png"
                  />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      
        <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 10px 10px 30px 90px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 50px; height: 57px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_6.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 10px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 74px; height: 58px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_7.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 10px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 57px; height: 64px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_8.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 10px 90px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 50px; height: 63px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_9.png"
                  />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mobile-icons" style="display: none;">
        <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 120px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 102px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_1.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 46px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_2.png"
                  />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 120px 30px 30px;">
              <img
                    style="width: 51px; height: 61px"
                    src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_3.png"
                  />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 120px;">
              <img
              style="width: 80px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_4.png"
            />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
              style="width: 64px; height: 61px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_5.png"
            />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 120px 30px 30px;">
              <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 57px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_6.png"
            />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 120px;">
              <img
              style="width: 74px; height: 58px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_7.png"
            />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 10px 30px 30px;">
              <img
              style="width: 57px; height: 64px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_8.png"
            />
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;
        padding: 30px 120px 30px 30px;">
              <img
              style="width: 50px; height: 63px"
              src="https://keen-pike-986d32.netlify.app/images/img_9.png"
            />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
      </div>
      
      <hr style="width: 63px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 30px" />
      
      <p
                style="
                  margin-bottom: 5px;
                  margin-top: 0;
                  font-size: 13px;
                  text-align: center;
                "
              >
                Questions? Contact hello@drinkboxt.com
              </p>
              <p
                style="
                  margin-top: 0;
                  margin-bottom: 30px;
                  font-size: 13px;
                  text-align: center;
                "
              >
                @drinkboxt | drinkboxt.com
              </p>
              <hr style="width: 63px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 37px" />
      
      <h3
                class="female-founded"
                style="
                  font-size: 13.5px;
                  margin-top: 0;
                  margin-bottom: 16px;
                  text-align: center;
                "
              >
                FEMALE FOUNDED. BORN IN AUSTIN. MADE IN NAPA.
              </h3>
              <hr
                class="big-divider"
                style="width: 85%; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 15px"
              />
      
      <table role="presentation" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 9.5px; margin-top: 0">
                *Excludes profiles Three and Six
              </p>
              <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 11px">
                DRINK BOXT LLC, 7601 S Congress Ave #150, Austin, TX 78745
              </p>
              <p
                class="last-paragraph"
                style="
                  text-align: center;
                  font-size: 11px;
                  padding-bottom: 97px;
                  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
                ">
                *Offer valid in the form of BOXT gift cards. Redeem up to 12 months of
                BOXT on us. Offer cannot be combined with any other promotion or new
                member offers and discounts, subject to DRINK BOXT, LLC Terms &
                Conditions. Void where prohibited. Subject to DRINK BOXT, LLC Terms &
                Conditions. Members never pay shipping and can pause, change profile
                or cancel at any time. Subscription is ongoing until canceled. Email
                communication is intended for those 21+. Must be 21+ to order and
                receive wine shipment. Void where prohibited. DRINK BOXT, LLC cannot
                ship to AK, AR, DE, HI, IN, MS, RI, UT, WV.
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```